# MMAP, "TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface" | Python

Tags: python-3.x, mmap

```
f = open('C:\Python33\File.doc')
s = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
if (s.find("blabla")) != -1:
    print("True")
```

When I run the following code, I get the error "TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface", why is this, and what can I do to solve this problem?

I have searched online for the answer, and a common result is to do with me using Python 3 over Python 2 and they way it treats data types. But I have not found a direct answer yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str`s are unicode codepoints, and they don't support the buffer interface (which basically means raw access to the memory underneath them). In general, you need to convert them into a `bytes` using [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode), or in this case you can just use a bytes literal instead of a str literal by putting on a `b` prefix.

```
if s.find(b'blabla') != -1:
    ...
```

[What Every Programmer Needs To Know About Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) has a pretty good explanation of why you need to use encode to get the bytes. This is why Python's `str` doesn't provide a buffer interface - you need to explicitly tell it the encoding before it knows what bytes should be in it.